# Is it grammatically ok to say "Of that, I'm sure" instead of "I'm sure of that"?

Tags: sentence-construction

Is it grammatically correct to say "**Of that**, I'm sure" instead of "I'm sure **of that**?
Examples:

> 1. My friend: Are you sure the covid-19 epidemic is gonna be done soon?
>    Me: ***Of that, I'm sure***.
> 2. We need peace, ***of that I'm sure***.

Comment: Yes, people say this.

Comment: It would be good if you add a coma after 'Of that'.

Comment: "My life is brilliant,
My love is pure,
I saw an angel.
Of that I'm sure" 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J43Z9XKj4DA

Answer (score 1):

> Of that I'm sure.

Yes it is correct. I would say it is unlikely to be heard in casual conversation and perhaps more likely in a speech or in writing.

**Real examples**

> No one in my adopted family had that name; of that I am sure.
>
> [Google
> Books](https://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1984%2Ccd_max%3A2019%2Clr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk03Zhz6klcQ3WA1_EujAPq_jyZwYGw%3A1608369713797&ei=McbdX4T_L5OT8gLEzaKwDw&q=%22of+that+i+am+sure%22&oq=%22of+that+i+am+sure%22&gs_l=psy-ab.12...459133.462453.0.466231.5.5.0.0.0.0.133.367.4j1.5.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.zlM0lLwAJj0)

> of that I am positive
>
> of that I am certain
>
> Of that I am clear
>
> of That I am most certain
>
> [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22of%20that%20i%20am%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1984,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en)

Comment: "My life is brilliant, My love is pure, I saw an angel. Of that I'm sure" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J43Z9XKj4DA

Comment: Can I conclude: although it's grammatically correct, in spoken English (British) it's better to say "I'm sure of that"?

Comment: It's always best to give a sample conversation showing how you yourself want to use the word or phrase. People don't usually  just stand outdoors and shout "I'm sure of that!"!  English usage is very dependent on context so we need to know how the (imaginary) conversation went before this in order to answer accurately.

Comment: Yeah, you're right it, you can't tell if something's right until you know the context.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there's no problem with **'Of that, I'm sure'**, provided you punctuate it correctly.
To be precise, there's no problem with starting a sentence with **'of'**. Poets are the ones, who take the most advantage of this. Though your sentences are grammatically correct, I would suggest some edits in them:

> "Of that, I'm sure."
> "We need peace. Of that, I'm sure."

Hope it helps:)

Comment: Yes. In speech-making, or in writing - and of course songs and  poems!

Comment: I am not so certain that a comma is needed in such a short sentence. In fact if you click through to the examples I gave in my answer, I don't think even one of them used a comma. Maybe you can find examples?

Comment: Of that, you're right. hmmmmmmmmmmmmmm. I mean Of that you're right. It's not really required to add that coma.